# Removing a dynamically created ViewGroup by dynamically created button

Tags: java, android, button, dynamic, view

I am developing an android termostat app, and I have made a listing (in code) of a group of items. Therefore I dynamically add buttons. When the user clicks on one of these buttons, I want to have all views having the same parent (LinearLayout) to be removed.

How can I write a piece of code that does that?

Below the code where I create this "entry".

```
private void createEntry(int entry){
    TableLayout my_root = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.day_root);
    LinearLayout A = new LinearLayout(this);
    A.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
    A.setId(DYN_LAYOUT_ID + entry);
    ImageView im1 = new ImageView(this);
    ImageView im2 = new ImageView(this);
    im1.setImageResource(R.drawable.sun_small);
    im2.setImageResource(R.drawable.moon_small);

    TextView tv = new TextView(this);
    Button btn = new Button(this);
    btn.setText("remove");

    tv.setText(new StringBuilder().append(pad(sHour)).append(":").append(pad(sMinute))
            .append(" - ").append(pad(eHour)).append(":").append(pad(eMinute)));
    tv.setTextSize(20);
    A.addView(im1);
    A.addView(tv);
    A.addView(im2);
    A.addView(btn);
    my_root.addView(A);
}
```

EDIT: my inital attemp which does seem to solve the problem (updated part of above code)

```
Button btn = new Button(this);
    btn.setId(BUTTON_ID + entry);
    btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            int row = v.getId() - BUTTON_ID;
            LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout) findViewById(DYN_LAYOUT_ID + row);
            ll.removeAllViewsInLayout();    
        }

    });
```

When btn is clicked, all views that belong to the LinearLayout to which this Button belongs are removed.

Answer (score 0):

All [`ViewGroup`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html)s have some flavors of `removeView()`. You may have to keep references to some of your views with instance variables.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! I checked all functions in particular for the "container" which is my LinearLayout. The function ll.removeAllViewsInLayout() did the trick!

Comment: Glad it helped. Also, you should use `removeAllViews()` instead. `removeAllViewsInLayout()` is for use during a layout traversal of the view hierarchy.